# Storing mysql pass in php script above web root, anything better?

Tags: php, mysql, security

So I'm storing my MySQL database connection login info in a .php file that's above the web root.

But if someone gains access to the whole server, they could potentially open that file up

What else can I do to protect the info?

Answer (score 5):

If someone has access to your entire production webserver, I figure you would have bigger issues than hiding your MySQL database credentials.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do anything against the person who got the access to the server.

Comment: You can slap them if they are local :P

Comment: @alex: unless they are bigger and/or stronger than you in which case alternative approaches are advised

Answer (score 2):

Besides the obvious answers, you should ensure your site is safe from [directory traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal) attacks that may read your PHP file above the root.

#### Make sure you don't do this (or similar)

```
echo file_get_contents($_GET['page']);
```

(better example than previous)

Comment: If its a php file then this will execute the file and an attacker will not be able to see its contents.

Comment: @Rook Yeah, the similar would be `echo file_get_contents($_GET['page']);`.